# DropdownList1 Has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anyone look at my code and tell me where this error may be stemming from?  I need my form to operate off the empid field in dropdownlist1 because my stored procedure requires the int value but when I change my DataValueField to EmpID I says that the SelectedValue in dropdownList one does not exist in the list of items.  Ive tried changing the SelectedValue to EmpId as well with no luck.  Any ideas?

.aspx

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project Lead">
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="Employee" 
    DataTextField="Project Lead" DataValueField="EmpId" 
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Project Lead") %>'>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Employee" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LandscapeServicesConnectionString %>" 

    SelectCommand="select EmpId, (firstname+' '+lastname) as &quot;Project Lead&quot; from  Employees ">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProjectLead") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle ForeColor="Black" Wrap="False" Font-Names="Arial" HorizontalAlign="Center"
    BackColor="Silver" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="11px" />
    <ItemStyle Font-Bold="False" Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="Black" Wrap="False"
    HorizontalAlign="Left" Font-Size="9px" />
```

aspx.cs

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using System.Data;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Configuration;

 namespace LandscapeServices
 {
 public partial class Update : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    public string query { get; set; }
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["LandscapeServicesConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    DataSet dt = new DataSet();
    string[] IApps;
    string[] SApps;
    ListBox lbImpactedApps;
    ListBox lbSupportingApps;
    ListBox ListBoxOne;
    ListBox ListBoxTwo;
    ListBox ListBoxThree;
    ListBox ListBoxFour;
    TextBox TextBoxOne;
    TextBox TextBoxTwo;
    DropDownList DropDownListOne;
    DropDownList DropDownListTwo;
    DropDownList DropDownListThree;
    DropDownList DropDownListFour;
    DropDownList DropDownListFive;
    DropDownList DropDownListSeven;
    DropDownList DropDownListEight;
    DropDownList DropDownListNine;
    TextBox Calendar1;
    TextBox Comments;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        //GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        string ImpactedApp = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView)(sender)).Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("Label10"))).Text;
        IApps = ImpactedApp.Split(',');

        string SupportingApp = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)(((System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView)(sender)).Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("Label11"))).Text;
        SApps = SupportingApp.Split(',');
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
                lbImpactedApps = (ListBox)e.Row.FindControl("ListBox1");
                lbSupportingApps = (ListBox)e.Row.FindControl("ListBox2");


                foreach (string lst in IApps)
                {
                    lbImpactedApps.Items.Add(lst.ToString());
                    //lbImpactedApps.Items.FindByText(lst.ToString()).Selected = true;

                }

                lbImpactedApps.DataBind();

                foreach (string lst in SApps)
                {
                    lbSupportingApps.Items.Add(lst.ToString());
                    //lbSupportingApps.Items.FindByText(lst.ToString()).Selected = true;

                }

                lbSupportingApps.DataBind();

            }
        }
    }



    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                ListBoxOne = row.FindControl("ListBox1") as ListBox;
                ListBoxThree = row.FindControl("ListBox3") as ListBox;
                if (ListBoxOne != null)
                    break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = ListBoxThree.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (ListBoxThree.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                ListBoxOne.Items.Add(new ListItem(ListBoxThree.Items[i].Text, ListBoxThree.Items[i].Value + ","));
            }
        }

    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                ListBoxOne = row.FindControl("ListBox1") as ListBox;
                if (ListBoxOne != null)
                    break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = ListBoxOne.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (ListBoxOne.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                ListBoxOne.Items.Remove(new ListItem(ListBoxOne.Items[i].Text, ListBoxOne.Items[i].Value));
            }
        }


    }


    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                ListBoxTwo = row.FindControl("ListBox2") as ListBox;
                ListBoxFour = row.FindControl("ListBox4") as ListBox;
                if (ListBoxTwo != null)
                    break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = ListBoxFour.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (ListBoxFour.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                ListBoxTwo.Items.Add(new ListItem(ListBoxFour.Items[i].Text, ListBoxFour.Items[i].Value + ","));
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                ListBoxTwo = row.FindControl("ListBox2") as ListBox;
                if (ListBoxTwo != null)
                    break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = ListBoxTwo.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (ListBoxTwo.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                ListBoxTwo.Items.Remove(new ListItem(ListBoxTwo.Items[i].Text, ListBoxTwo.Items[i].Value));
            }
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        if (con.ConnectionString == "")
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                ListBoxOne = row.FindControl("ListBox1") as ListBox;
                ListBoxTwo = row.FindControl("ListBox2") as ListBox;
                TextBoxOne = row.FindControl("txtProjectName") as TextBox;
                TextBoxTwo = row.FindControl("txtArtemisNumber") as TextBox;
                DropDownListOne = row.FindControl("DropDownList1") as DropDownList;
                DropDownListTwo = row.FindControl("DropDownList2") as DropDownList;
                DropDownListThree = row.FindControl("DropDownList3") as DropDownList;
                DropDownListFour = row.FindControl("DropDownList4") as DropDownList;
                DropDownListFive = row.FindControl("DropDownList5") as DropDownList;
                DropDownListSeven = row.FindControl("DropDownList7") as DropDownList;
                DropDownListEight = row.FindControl("DropDownList8") as DropDownList;
                DropDownListNine = row.FindControl("DropDownList9") as DropDownList;
                Calendar1 = row.FindControl("ImplementationDate") as TextBox;
                Comments = row.FindControl("txtComments") as TextBox;

                string ListBox1Values = "";
                for (int i = ListBoxOne.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    ListBox1Values += ListBoxOne.Items[i].Value;
                }
                if (ListBoxOne.Items.Count == 0)
                {
                    ListBox1Values = "1075";
                }
                ListBox1Values = ListBox1Values.TrimEnd(',');

                string ListBox2Values = "";
                for (int i = ListBoxTwo.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    ListBox2Values += ListBoxTwo.Items[i].Value;
                }
                if (ListBoxTwo.Items.Count == 0)
                {
                    ListBox2Values = "1075";
                }
                ListBox2Values = ListBox2Values.TrimEnd(',');

                //Execute Stored proc
                query = "EXEC USP_UPDATE_PROJECTS '" + TextBoxOne.Text.ToString() + "','" + 
                    TextBoxTwo.Text.ToString() + "','" + 
                    DropDownListOne.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + 
                    DropDownListTwo.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + 
                    DropDownListThree.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + 
                    DropDownListFour.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" +
                    DropDownListFive.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + 
                    DropDownListEight.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + 
                    DropDownListNine.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + 
                    ListBox1Values + "','" + 
                    ListBox2Values + "','" + 
                    Calendar1.Text + "','" + 
                    DropDownListSeven.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + 
                    Comments.Text.ToString() + "','" + "'";

                //con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: wow that is one long spaghetti code :((((((( can't look, my eyes bleed. Rule #1 KEEP IT SIMPLE

Comment: Did you try to bind from code behind? you will get the source of error instantly.

Comment: Only glanced through your code as it's 1 long load of it. However, it looks like your trying to execute your stored procedure on RowUpdating. This gets the values in GridView1 BEFORE the row is updated. Are you sure this is what you want to be doing? You might want to do it on RowUpdated.

Comment: Also, if you want someone to know you've replied to them use the '@' symbol in front of their name like @sr28.

Comment: @RanajitChatterjee Im not sure exactly what you mean, can you demonstrate?

Comment: @sr28 The goal of this is to see the gridview, manually edit the items, update and have the stored procedure update the tables in sql.  If this is the improper way of doing it, I am all eyes

Comment: http://www.ezineasp.net/post/ASP-Net-DropDownList-SQL-Datasource-Databinding.aspx

Comment: This isn't an answer to your problem, just advice. Names are really important. Really, really important. You must be able to think of better names than `DropDownListFour` and `Button3_Click`. As all those Lists ultimately end up as parameters in a stored procedure the names should be easy to come by. It not only helps others read your code it helps you understand it too.

Comment: Try changing this line:

    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Project Lead") %>'>

This makes the selected value the 'Project Lead'. Surely you want to make the SelectedValue EmpId?

Comment: @sr28 A decent suggestion however when I try this I end up with DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'EmpId'.